# animals that are not "primates"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there **a specific term** to refer to all animals that are not *primates*? I have a text about the beginnings of brain research, in which the animals studied are divided into "simple animals" (mice, guinea pig, mole, rabbit, reptiles etc.) and "complex mammals and humans" (monkeys, apes, humans). The latter are *primates*, but I have no idea how to refer to the former group ("simple animals" is so imprecise). I tried on Wiki, but I got completely lost in all those Latin scientific classifications...

Comment: How about _non-primates_?

Comment: Sure, but I thought maybe there's some specific term.

Answer (score 3):

Popular imagination, at least in the parts of the English-speaking world with which I can claim some familiarity, does not subdivide the world into primates and non-primates. This is not a traditional distinction— no traditional grouping would have included humans, orangutans, and lemurs in the same collective—and as a scientific categorization, the division is useful only so far as it is for *any* subdivision of animals: ungulates, annelids, hummingbirds.

Animals which are not primates are simply ***[nonprimates](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/evan.20172)*** (or ***non-primates***), just as we might add non-ungulates, non-annelids, and non-hummingbirds to the conversation. Biologists may have more specialized terminology, but none that has made its way into popular usage. *Nonprimate* is certainly a term one [can find](https://doi.org/10.1159/000155669) in [primatology](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10764-014-9792-2) journals.

Separate terminology is more common when the distinguishing characteristics are more readily observable than genetic maps, and when the groups are conceptually more equal. Traditional divisions include *[vertebrate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vertebrate)* and *[invertebrate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/invertebrate)* animals and *[warm-blooded](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/warm-blooded)* and *[cold-blooded](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cold-blooded)* animals, and more nebulously, the divisions between *large* and *small* animals and between *higher* and *[lower animals](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-lower-animals)*, the boundaries of which no two people will always agree upon.

Comment: But isn't it that _non-primates_ are first understood as _**mammals** that aren't primates_? I'd like to put non-primates, non-ungulates, the cold-blooded and invertebrate (etc.) under one term.

Comment: @shogun First understood among whom? The scope is established by context. Non-primates include not just sparrows and horses but spiders, archae, the planet Jupiter, and the completing the square method of factoring quadratic equations, for a certain kind of semiotician or philosopher.